# Issue with creating a column using np.where, ArrayType error

Tags: python, np

I have a dataframe in which I'm trying to create a binary 1/0 column when certain conditions are met.  The code I'm using is as follows:

```
sd_threshold = 5

df1["signal"] = np.where(np.logical_and(df1["high"] >= df1["break"], df1["low"] 
<= df1["break"], df1["sd_round"] > sd_threshold), 1, 0)
```

The code returns `TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType` when the last condition `df1["sd_round"] > sd_threshold` is included, otherwise it works fine.  There isn't any issue with the data in the df1["sd_round"] column.

Any insight would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[check the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) -- `np.logical_and()` compares the first two arguments you give it and writes the output to the third. you could use a nested call but i would just go with `&` ([pandas boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)):

```
df1["signal"] = np.where((df1["high"] >= df1["break"]) & 
                         (df1["low"] <= df1["break"]) &
                         (df1["sd_round"] > sd_threshold), 
                         1, 0)
```

EDIT: you could actually just skip numpy and cast your boolean Series to int to yield 1s and 0s:

```
mask = ((df1["high"] >= df1["break"]) & 
        (df1["low"] <= df1["break"]) &
        (df1["sd_round"] > sd_threshold))
df1["signal"] = mask.astype(int)
```